# How do I find the target state during a transition start

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to find the next state when I start transition. I've written code to show  launch a modal that shows a message to the user in case the form is dirty, but I don't want to show this message even the form is dirty when the transition is being done to certain states. Is there a service that I can inject to find the next state I'm transitioning to.

```
$transitions.onStart({}, () => {

  //here I want to add a condition to not launch this modal if the $state name is xyz, otherwise just show the modal

  if (($scope.form.$dirty)) {
                return $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: '/app/shared/modalDialog.html',
                    controller: 'ModalDialogController',
                    controllerAs: 'modal',
                    resolve: {
                        modalOptions: function () {
                            return {
                                headerText: 'Unsaved Changes',
                                bodyText: 'There are unsaved changes on this page. Are you sure you want to leave?',
                                primaryText: 'Continue',
                                secondaryText: 'Cancel'
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }).result
                 .then(result => {
                        if (result === 'secondary')
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
}
}
```

Comment: I've resolved this by following https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks. I'm checking the state name using the code snippet $transitions.onStart({}, function(transition) {
  if (transition.to().name === 'sloth') {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that `angular-ui-router` broadcasts various state events including `$stateChangeStart`. We have a global controller where we register a handler for this event:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (
    event,
    toState,
    toParams,
    fromState,
    fromParams) => {
        // code goes here to examine to the 'toState' parameter
        // and take any appropriate action
    });
```